# CF9.0.1 ORM: "orderby" attribute on "many-to-many" references column on wrong table

Tags: hibernate, sorting, orm, coldfusion, many-to-many

I just ran into a strange error:

```
could not initialize a collection: [webServiceAction.aAssignedApplication#7]
```

which makes more sense after looking at the root cause:

```
[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Invalid column name 'sName'
```

Basically, Hibernate tries to find the sort column inside the link table instead of the one table behind the referenced entity. Not sure how to tell Hibernate the correct location.

There are two entities (webServiceAction.cfc and app.cfc) linked through a table in a many-to-many relationship. Both implement a HasName.cfc interface among other interfaces..

.

Section from `webServiceAction.cfc`:

```xml
<cfproperty name="aAssignedApplication" 
    fieldtype="many-to-many"  
    CFC="model.app" 
    linktable="G_TRelWebserviceActionAssignment" 
    fKColumn="fkWebserviceActionID" 
    inversejoincolumn="fkApplicationID" 
    lazy="true" 
    cascade="delete-orphan"  
    orderby="sName">
```

.

SQL captured through a profiler listening to the MS SQL database:

```sql
select aassigneda0_.fkWebserviceActionID as fkWebser2_5_1_, 
   aassigneda0_.fkApplicationID      as fkApplic1_1_, 
   app1_.pkApplicationID             as pkApplic1_0_0_, 
   app1_.sName                       as sName0_0_, 
   app1_.sUUID                       as sUUID0_0_, 
   app1_.sToken                      as sToken0_0_, 
   app1_.sDescription                as sDescrip5_0_0_, 
   app1_.dCreateDate                 as dCreateD6_0_0_ 
from G_TRelWebserviceActionAssignment aassigneda0_ 
inner join G_TApplication             app1_ on aassigneda0_.fkApplicationID=app1_.pkApplicationID 
where aassigneda0_.fkWebserviceActionID=? 
order by aassigneda0_.sName
```

As you can see from the last line in the SQL block, Hibernate ends up trying to find the name column in the link table instead of the actual table behind the app.cfc objects.

I've already tried a more specific notation by prepending it with the entity and table names, but those attempts didn't work out either.

Thanks in advance for any attempts to point me in the right direction. 
I'd probably be able to fix it using a formula or by writing the XML file myself, but I'd like to avoid that, if possible.

**Addendum:**
My cascade settings were too aggressive and `cascade="save-update"` is enough for this task, but the main problem still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is expected behavior in hibernate if you set the order by in the set definition. there is also an orderby in the manytomanydefinition which does what you want, but i do not know how to state this in coldfusion

```
<bag table="linktable" order-by="column in linktable">
  <key column="idcol" />
  <many-to-many order-by="column in other table">
    <column name="" />
  </many-to-many>
</bag>
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up!
Basically, the ColdFusion attributes are translated into annotations for the resulting class files.

.

BTW: I ended up writing a custom getter for the property. It's not possible to customize the toString() method of a resulting class or I would've simply used the Collection sort method to do the dirty work for me.